# How to concatenate variable with anchor's href

Tags: php

I'm noob in php, and i'm trying to concatenate href with words or values ex:

```
$name = "anonymous";
echo '<a href = "profile.php">'.$name.'</a><br/>';
```

I want it to look like this when the user clicked the link.

```
echo '<a href = "profile.php/anonymous">'.$name.'</a><br/>';
```

I've tried doing this, but it's not working.

```
echo '<a href = "profile.php/<?php echo $name;?>">'.$name.'</a><br/>';
```

Comment: PHP cannot be embedded within php like that and still execute. It's not like Inception where you can go down as many levels as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<a href = "profile.php/'.$name.'">'.$name.'</a><br/>';
```

The same way you concatenated the text.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use php tags inside a php tag like this,

```
echo '<a href = "profile.php/<?php echo $name;?>">'.$name.'</a><br/>';
```

It will mess the PHP interpreter so use this

```
echo "<a href=profile.php/{$name}>".$name."</a><br/>";
```